# Ctrl-F no longer works to accept suggestions. Why?

Tags: shell, fish

I recently enabled Vi mode by adding `fish_vi_mode` to my config. Since I did this <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> no longer works to complete suggestions, I have to use Right Arrow instead.

The keybindings for `forward-char` are the same with or without `fish_vi_mode` enabled. According to `fish_config`, they are:

```
forward-char    Right Arrow
forward-char    Right Arrow
forward-char    CTRL - f
```

Why doesn't <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> work with `fish_vi_mode` enabled?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In vi mode, run `bind` and look for `\cf`, it's here:

```
bind -M insert \cf forward-word
```

that's what's going on: control-F is going forward by a word. You can restore the non-vi behavior:

```
bind -M insert \cf forward-char
```

which is to go forward by one character, or accept the autosuggestion if the cursor is at the end (which is admittedly sort of weird).

Or if you want it to only accept the autosuggestion, you can run this after `fish_vi_mode`:

```
bind -M insert \cf accept-autosuggestion
```

Now it accepts the autosuggestion at any point, not just at the end.

BTW, these functions like `accept-autosuggestion` or `forward-char` can be listed via `bind --function-names`

*Edit*: this is harder than it ought to be due to [#2254](https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/2254). The simplest thing is to put the call to `fish_vi_mode` in the `fish_user_key_bindings` function:

```
function fish_user_key_bindings
    fish_vi_mode
    bind -M insert \cf accept-autosuggestion
    bind \cf accept-autosuggestion
end
```

You can use `funced fish_user_key_bindings` to write that function, and then `funcsave fish_user_key_bindings` to save it.

Comment: Thanks for the response. But adding the `bind` lines into my config doesn't seen have any affect. I added it after the `fish_vi_mode` line. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Perhaps you're running fish_vi_mode twice?

Run `bind` - is your new accept-autosuggestion binding present? What happens if you run `bind -M insert \cf accept-autosuggestion` just at the commandline?

Comment: It's not present when I add it to the config file only. If I run `bind` manually then it works. My config looks like this: https://gist.github.com/jordelver/9faa99fe7eff98ff8dca Do I need to kill off all fish sessions or will opening a new terminal be enough?

Comment: Ugh - ok, this is harder than it ought to be due to [#2254](https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/2254). I've edited my reply with what I think the best approach is.

Comment: That works. Thank you very much for all your help. Great work on fish :)

Answer (score -1):

To amend the previous accepted answer, according to Fish release notes (https://fishshell.com/docs/current/relnotes.html?highlight=vi_mode), you'll need to replace `fish_vi_mode` with `fish_vi_key_bindings`.

Comment: Good (and correct) info, but it really needs to be an edit or a comment on the existing answer, since this info doesn't attempt to answer the question itself.  I know you don't have enough rep to comment on others's posts, but (I don't recall) can you propose an edit?  In searching some Meta questions, I *think* you can.  If you propose an edit to the existing answer, note that the change occurred in [2.3b2 and later](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/relnotes.html?highlight=vi_mode#fish-2-3b2-released-may-5-2016).